# How is chrono::steady_clock's rep and period types determined?

Tags: c++, clock, duration, c++-chrono

[`chrono::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) consists of 4 member types: `rep`, `period`, `duration`, and `timepoint`.

`chrono::steady_clock::duration` is a `chrono::duration<rep,period>`.
`chrono::steady_clock::period` is a `ratio`.

How are the types of `chrono::steady_clock::duration` and `chrono::steady_clock::period` determined?

For example,

`chrono::steady_clock::duration` could be `chrono::duration<int,period>` where period is `ratio<1,1000>`

or

`chrono::steady_clock::duration` could be `chrono::duration<double,period>` where period is `ratio<1,1000000>`.

Answer (score 6):

> `chrono::steady_clock` consists of 4 member types: `rep`,
>   `period`, `duration`, and `timepoint`.
>
> `chrono::stead_clock::duration` is a `chrono::duration<rep,period>`.
>   `chrono::steady_clock::period` is a `ratio`.

Yes.

> How are the types of `chrono::stead_clock::duration` and
>   `chrono::steady_clock::period` determined?

They are somewhat implementation specific, but there do exist constraints and invariants among these types.

`1.` `rep` must be a pretty well-behaved arithmetic-like type.  It must have a default constructor, copy constructor, copy assignment and it has non-surprising semantics, and doesn't throw exceptions.  The de facto standard is that all `steady_clock::rep` are signed integral 64 bit types.

`2.` `period` is pretty much up in the air.  That being said, VS, libstdc++ and libc++ all have `steady_clock::period` set to `nano`.

`3.` `duration` must have a very specific relationship to `rep` and `period`:  `is_same<duration, chrono::duration<rep, period>>{}` is `true_type`.  It doesn't matter much if you specify `duration` first and derive `rep` and `period` from that, or vice-versa.  But the invariant must hold.

`4.` `time_point` shall be an instantiation of `std::chrono::time_point` with a duration of `duration`.  It is unspecified what the `time_point`'s clock is.  However what type that clock is, it must have the same epoch as `steady_clock`.  This is arguably a defect and should have the constraint that `steady_clock::time_point::clock` is `steady_clock`.  The de facto standard is that this constraint holds.

Answer (score 3):

The `rep` and `period` are unspecified by the standard. Each standard library implementation may choose their own. If the underlying timing calls they use have a precision of 100ns, choosing a period of `std::ratio<100, 1000000000>` seems like a good idea.

There are a few [requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialClock) those types must satisfy, but it's pretty much up to the implementation.

`duration` is always just based on `rep` and `period`... `std::chrono::duration<rep, period>`

Comment: So if I'm using Visual Studio and I use `#include <chrono>`, does that mean the `chrono` is implemented by Microsoft?

Comment: The std::chrono::clocks are required to have time_points/durations based on signed integral types which a range of at least +/-292 years.  This requirement is not put on programmer-defined clocks.